# Unwanted borders in unordered list menu

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to figure out where the border on the horizontal menu items comes (based on a unordered list): http://developers.ttsistemi.com/clive/

I've tried everything.
I've even tried to set the border (and just in case the background, padding and margin) to none/transparent/0, to main element and it children, but I still get this annoying border (you can barely see it, but is there, between all menu items).

The site is in WordPress and uses a Required+ child theme (based on Zurb's Foundation).

I've spend something like 4 hours trying to find where this border comes from (inspecting the CSS with Chrome's developer tools) but I'm stuck. I just don't see any border setting leftover: everything that might have been set by the parent theme should be everything overridden by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For `.navbar > li` delete these properties that are currently set:

```
.navbar > li {
box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset; /* Delete */
border-width: 1px medium 1px 1px; /* Delete */
border-style: solid none solid solid; /* Delete */
border-color: #333333 -moz-use-text-color #333333 #333333; /* Delete */
```

2) Because your last `<li>` is selected using the `:last-child` pseudo-selector you must change it separately or else you'll have a border on the last menu-item. So remove:

```
.navbar > li:last-child {
border-right: 1px solid #333333; /* Delete */
box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, 
            1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); /* Delete */
```

---

Here is the screenshot showing the missing borders/box-shadow

http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/5845/menu2b.jpg

Comment: The box shadow was the actual issue: border were already disabled by my own CSS. I focused on the borders, without realizing that what I was seeing was a shadow.

By the way, from the screenshow, I think you were looking at the wrong page: only the home page has been styled for the moment. All other page still need to be themed.

You've got the solution anyway: thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have take a look and just don't know what border do you want to remove, maybe the border in the menu, I found it here:

```
.home #container #content-wrapper #access {
   font-family: 'Museo Slab';
   width: 100%;
   border-top: 1px solid black;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   background-color: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.5);
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

in app.css line 101, remove this border it won't display anymore.

In Dark's answer, I checked it too:
I think the width of `nav id="access"` is incorrect, it should change like this:

```
.eight, .row .eight {
width: 38.66667%;
}
```

I saw your `background-image` on footer make the text hard to look, I recommend you should remove it or add a space for them.

Comment: Not sure which page you were looking at. The only page you should have looked is the home page: all other pages are not meant to be seen yet, as currently I'm working only on the home page. The home page has no text in the footer: there isn't any "hard to look" text :)

Comment: However, Perfect Dark answer is the one I was looking to. Thank you.